# Comparing strings from two large arrays for printing

Tags: arrays, ruby, compare

Beginner at Ruby here.

I have two text files, FILE1.txt and FILE2.txt(3gb). I am trying to take each of the register names from FILE1.txt to find keywords that are similar to FILE2.txt as that contains the paths of the registers that I need.

For example:

**FILE1.txt:**

```
STRING_THAT_MATCHES_FILE1
STRING_THAT_DOES_NOT_MATCH
STRING_THAT_DOES_NOT_MATCH_2
```

**3gb text FILE2.txt:**

```
SYS.abcd.abcd.abcd.STRING_THAT_MATCHES_FILE1    6067d88dh
SYS.efgh.ijkl.abcd.doesnt_match 0h
```

When I try to compare the files such as the following code, I get empty array

```
$: << File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__), 'Ruby' )

require 'csv'
require 'etc'
require 'timeout'
require 'date'
require 'set'


paths_file = 'FILE2.txt'
register_file = 'FILE1.txt'

register_array = Array.new
paths_array = Array.new
compared = Array.new

File.foreach(register_file).with_index do |regs|
   register_array << regs

  File.foreach(paths_file).with_index do |paths|
  paths_array << paths

   if regs.include? paths
  compared << paths
  print compared
  end
  end
  end
```

This is the output that I get:

```
["\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n", "\n"]
```

Comment: Please edit to show the desired output, which I assume is an array.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `.with_index do |regs|` → `#with_index` yields to a λ with _two_ arguments, so you get an array in `regs`. Also, I am not sure why would you need `with_index` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Something like the below should work.

```rb
matchers = Regexp.union(File.readlines('FILE1.txt'), chomp: true)
File.foreach('FILE2.txt').with_index.with_object({}) do |(e, idx), h|
  h[idx] = e if e =~ matchers
end
```

Comment: You might need to add the `chomp: true` option when reading *FILE1.txt*. Otherwise the terminating newline will be part of the regex. The same can be done for *FILE2.txt* if OP wants a result without terminating newlines. I would also suggest using `e.match?(matchers)` over `e =~ matchers` since it's less cryptic, but that's just personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Expending upon the [answer of Aleksei Matiushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59711448/3982562). I would go with a version that looks a bit different:

```
register_names = File.readlines('FILE1.txt', chomp: true)
register_names_regex = Regexp.union(register_names)
found_registers = File.foreach('FILE2.txt').with_index
                      .select { |line, _index| line.match?(register_names_regex) }
                      .to_h(&:reverse)
#=> {0=>"SYS.abcd.abcd.abcd.STRING_THAT_MATCHES_FILE1    6067d88dh\n"}
```

If you're not interested in the indexes, but only in the lines themself you could simplify the above to:

```
register_names = File.readlines('FILE1.txt', chomp: true)
register_names_regex = Regexp.union(register_names)
found_registers = File.foreach('FILE2.txt').grep(register_names_regex)
#=> ["SYS.abcd.abcd.abcd.STRING_THAT_MATCHES_FILE1    6067d88dh\n"]
```

If you don't want/need the terminating newline character at the end of the line change `File.foreach('FILE2.txt')` into `File.foreach('FILE2.txt', chomp: true)`.

Comment: Interesting, grep did shorten the code quite a bit so thank you for that. However, original problem still lies:

#=> {0=>"SYS.abcd.abcd.abcd.STRING_THAT_MATCHES_FILE1    6067d88dh\n"} 

The above does not work, however, if I delete the space such as this:
#=> {0=>"SYS.abcd.abcd.abcd.STRING_THAT_MATCHES_FILE1\n"} 

Then the grep finds the string. I have tried to use .split (" ") however, that does not recognize the string either

Comment: @AmateurGamer What do you mean the above does not work? What doesn't work? What output are you getting? `#=> {0=>"SYS.abcd.abcd.abcd.STRING_THAT_MATCHES_FILE1 6067d88dh\n"}` is the output I get and isn't part of the solution code (it's a comment).